# react-custom-scrollbars - how to change horizontal scroll track color?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, scrollbar

I use [react-custom-scrollbars](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars) for customized horizontal scroll.

```
<Scrollbars ref="scrollio" 
    onScroll={this.onScroll} 
    renderThumbHorizontal={props => <div {...props} className="thumb-horizontal"/>}
    autoHeight='true' autoHeightMax={Number.MAX_VALUE} renderTrackVertical={() => <div></div>} >

    <p>Some great content...Some great content...</p>

</Scrollbars>
```

And css file contains:

```
.thumb-horizontal {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px !important;
}
```

The code above works well and I get the scroll with red thumb but after adding track info scroll view disappears:

```
renderTrackHorizontal={props => <div {...props} className="track-horizontal"/>}
```

And:

```
.track-horizontal {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 10px !important;
}
```

How to set horizontal scroll track style in `react-custom-scrollbars`?

Comment: Can u add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in codepen or similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `left` and `bottom` properties because it was in the top right.

```
.track-horizontal {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 10px !important;
}
```

Similar issue: [Adding className to track (horizontal or vertical) breaks functionality](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars/issues/139)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way

```
<Scrollbars
    autoHide
    autoHideTimeout={1000}
    autoHideDuration={200}
    renderTrackVertical={({style, ...props}) =>
        <div {...props} className={s.scrollTrackVertical} style={{...style, backgroundColor: 'blue', right: '2px', bottom: '2px', top: '2px', borderRadius: '3px', width: '5px'}}/>
    }
    renderThumbVertical={({style, ...props}) =>
        <div {...props} className={s.scrollThumbVertical} style={{...style, width: '3px', borderRadius: '4px', boxShadow: '0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)', backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}}/>
    }>
</Scrollbars>
```